# How to show that derivative of $\phi(v)$ with respect to $v$ is $\phi'( v)= a(1-\phi^2(v))/2$

Tags: derivatives

How to show that derivative of  $\phi(v)$ with respect to $v$ is 
$$\frac{d \phi}{d v}= \frac{a}{2}(1-\phi^2(v)),$$ 
where 
$$\phi(v) = \frac{1-\exp(-av)}{1-\exp(-av)}=\tanh(av/2).$$ 
What is the value of derivative at the origin? Let's assume that slope parameter $a$ is infinitely big. What kind of equation of $\phi(v)$ you end up?

Comment: What do you mean by "assume the slope parameter $a$ is infinitely big"?

Comment: It might mean: "assume slope parameter a goes to infinity". I quess I'm quite certain of that.

Comment: So you're asking for the behavior of the solution as $a\to \infty$?

Comment: yes. What would be the function $\phi(v)$, if $a \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(\tanh(av/2))=(a/2)$sech$^2(av/2)$, and sech$^2(x)=1-\tanh^2(x)$.

Comment: May you show step please, i am new to differential equations.

Comment: Write out the $\tanh$ function using exponentials and then try to get the above relations. Check the wikipedia article on hyperbolic trigonometric functions.